# How to speed up MySQL query involving a "like" condition on a varchar column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a `varchar` column that contains stock market tickers. The values can have the stock exchange prepended to the actual ticker, but some don't. For example:

```
NYSE:MSFT
NYSE:AAPL
AMT:STZ
^SPX
JMAT
```

These are all valid tickers. Now, when someone searches for a ticker, then the query looks something like:

```
select * from stocks where ticker like '%'.$string.'%'
```

The table, in production, will have over 100k entries. I want to get ahead of that potential problem by indexing on the column, but it appears based on MySQL docs that it is not possible, not for a query like this anyway.

The docs state that a `varchar` `index` is possible, but in a `like` query it won't work if there's a wildcard *before* the search string. And I do need a wildcard before the search string.

Is there another option to speeding up this query?

Comment: How many possible prefixes are there?

Comment: I would be sorely tempted to clean ('normalise') the data, before continuing

Comment: @Strawberry There's at least about 200 possible prefixes, plus there are some stocks with no prefix.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to speed up the query you'll need to **avoid matching with patterns that start with a `%`**. To do this you'll need to add some redundancy to keep the second value in a separate column.

Therefore, your table should look like:

```
full_ticker  ticker
-----------  ------
NYSE:MSFT    MSFT
NYSE:AAPL    AAPL
AMT:STZ      STZ
^SPX         ^SPX
JMAT         JMAT
```

Simple string manipulation will produce the second (new) column; for 100k rows this will take no time.

Now you can create two indexes, one per column:

```
create index ix1 on stocks (full_ticker);

create index ix2 on stocks (ticker);
```

Finally, when a search comes in **with a colon**, then use the first index:

```
select * from stocks where full_ticker like $string.'%'
```

If a search comes in **without a colon**, then use the second index:

```
select * from stocks where ticker like $string.'%'
```

Notice that both searches avoid using the `%` at the beginning of the pattern. This way, your queries will use the indexes and will be blazing fast.

**A final note:** Another option is to create the second, redundant column as a "virtual column"; virtual columns can actually be indexed, to produce the same experience I detailed here. Just a though.

Comment: This makes sense. It's not an ideal solution however, since a user is likely to search "SPX" for example, and they should find the result "^SPX"...which means that I would still need to start the search on the short column with a wildcard...which negates the main benefit of this approach. Something to think about though for sure.

Comment: @jovan Then that's a different question now.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear at first, I added ^SPX in the list for this very reason but I guess I didn't explain it clearly.

Comment: This is specific to tickers starting with "^" or some other symbol. If the ticker is MSFT, then searching FT should *not* find the result MSFT.

Comment: @jovan The `^` case seems to be a third case. For this scenario you could 1) create a third column without the special symbol `^` (or other special symbols), or 2) you could create synonym rows. Or even simpler, when populating the second column, just strip the `^` out.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, there is no possibility to use index in combination with using '%wildcard%'.
There is possibility to use feature called: Full Text Searching (FTS), that can improve your searching performence in comparison with using LIKE operator.

Some example performance analysis is [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/12813-performance-analysis-of-mysql-s-fulltext-indexes-and-like-queries-for-full-text-search)

There is a lot of discussions about FTS, you can read on StackOverflow ofcourse.